# Is there a command to delete items from an org list?

Tags: org-mode

I have an `org-mode` list.

```
1) John
2) Paul
3) Jimmy
4) George
5) Ringo
```

I've decided that item number three doesn't belong on this list. I can purge this item by removing it and then issuing `C-c C-c` and the list updates.

```
1) John
2) Paul
3) George
4) Ringo
```

Is there a command to do this automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no command that I am aware of.

But one can adapt the [code of `org-move-item-down`](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/release_9.3.1/lisp/org-list.el#L2152-L2171) to that task:

```el
(defun org+-kill-list-item (&optional delete)
  "Kill list item at POINT.
Delete if DELETE is non-nil.
In interactive calls DELETE is the prefix arg."
  (interactive "P")
  (unless (org-at-item-p) (error "Not at an item"))
  (let* ((col (current-column))
         (item (point-at-bol))
         (struct (org-list-struct)))
    (org-list-send-item item (if delete 'delete 'kill) struct)
    (org-list-write-struct struct (org-list-parents-alist struct))
    (org-list-repair)
    (org-move-to-column col)))
```

Tested with Emacs 26.3 and Org 9.2.3.